# Iron Python throws exception on testing environment

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, ironpython

I'm having a code which runs Iron Python scripts on VS 2010. Every time a test completes I get an exception of type `ObjectDisposedException`, with the description: **Cannot write to a closed TextWriter**. I can't see the stack trace. I'm accessing the scripts via this wrapper:

```
public static class PythonWrapper
    {
        public static dynamic GetClient(string clientName, string clientType)
        {
            var file = string.Format(@"{0}\Python\webcore.eas", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            dynamic result = null;
            var ipy = GetRuntime();
            var engine = ipy.GetEngine("py");

            ScriptScope clientScope = engine.CreateScope();
            if(File.Exists(file))
            {
                clientScope.SetVariable("asm", Assembly.Load(ServiceManager.Get<FileEncryptionSevice>().Decrypt(file)));
                string dllWrapper = string.Format("import clr\n" +
                                                  "clr.AddReference(asm)\n" + 
                                                  "from Clients.{0} import {1}\n" +
                                                  "del clr", clientName, clientType);
                var src = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(dllWrapper);
                var compiled = src.Compile();
                compiled.Execute(clientScope);

                result = clientScope.GetVariable(clientType);
            }
            else
            {
                var scope = ipy.UseFile(string.Format(@"{0}\Python\Clients\{1}.py", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),clientName));
                result = scope.GetVariable(clientType);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static ScriptRuntime GetRuntime()
        {
            var result = Python.CreateRuntime();
            var engine = Python.GetEngine(result);
            var baseFolder = string.Format(@"{0}\Python\", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            engine.SetSearchPaths(new[] { 
                                         string.Format("{0}", baseFolder), 
                                         string.Format(@"{0}\Lib\", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                        });

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I guess I'm attempting to access a disposed object but none of the scripting objects is IDisposable. I've also tried calling ScriptRuntime.ShutDown at the end of each test, but it only has the test stuck.

Please help me.

Kind regards,

Izhar

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple bug of setting an output stream for the iron python. The following code solved the error

```
private static void SetOutputStream(ScriptEngine engine)
        {
            ScriptScope sys = engine.GetSysModule();
            sys.SetVariable("stdout", new PythonStreamWrapper(LogLevel.Debug));
            sys.SetVariable("stderr", new PythonStreamWrapper(LogLevel.Debug));
        }

public class PythonStreamWrapper
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger = LoggerService.GetLogger("Obj.Gen");


        private LogLevel _logLevel;

        public PythonStreamWrapper(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            _logLevel = logLevel;
        }

        public void write(string text)
        {
            if (text.Trim() == "") return;
            _logger.Write(_logLevel, text);
        }

        public int softspace
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```